# Postfix 554 <demo@demoslice.com>: Relay access denied

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, configuration, email-server

I am trying to set postfix up and I am running into some problems.....here are my files

```
vim /etc/postfix/main.cf

relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_connection_cache_destinations = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_CAfile= /etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_scert_verifydepth = 9


append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

myhostname = maggie.deliverypath.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = maggie.deliverypath.com, localhost.deliverypath.com, , localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

I also have the gmail password info

```
 vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

 gmail-smtp.l.google.com someuser@gmail.com:somepass
 smtp.gmail.com someuser@gmail.com:somepass
```

then I try to follow this [article](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/8/6/postfix-using-telnet-to-test-postfix) and i get this output

```
telnet mail.demoslice.com 25
Trying 67.207.128.80...
Connected to www.slicehost.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 www.slicehost.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
HELO test.demoslice.com
250 www.slicehost.com
MAIL FROM:<paul@demoslice.com>
250 Ok
RCPT TO:<demo@demoslice.com>
554 <demo@demoslice.com>: Relay access denied
```

its started

```
service postfix start
 * Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix
...done.
```

then the screen freezes and I can't do anything....any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're testing against mail.demoslice.com.  Try testing against your own mail server :)

Also, I have no idea what you mean by `then the screen gets frozen and i cant do anything....`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you aren't doing any authentication, relay access will be denied unless you connect from one of the my_network hosts.  So telnet localhost 25 will get further, or using a rcpt to user@maggie.deliverypath.com that you have on the server.